# JMeter response "Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException"

Tags: jmeter

I`m a new using Jmeter to do Load testing.
I have set testing regarding Login transaction，it posted with username and password,after I run it, it responses

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect
```

and response message:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:508)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:498)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: it's a general error, you need to provide more details, make sure port number is valid, if you are using HTTP/HTTPs and method as GET/POST...

Comment: I`m using HTTPS with method POST  to test login, I set the port as deafult 8080

Comment: 8080 is HTTP not HTTPS

Comment: thanks for your kindly help,request successed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request sending in port 8080 which is by default (can be changed) using HTTP connector and not HTTPS.

You need to change [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)'s protocol to HTTP.

Comment: you can accept the answer by clicking on the V sign to the left